# How many divisors does $n\alpha$ have?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

if $$\frac {p^\alpha - 1}{p - 1}= 2^n \hspace{5 mm} n,\alpha \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{5 mm} p\in\mathbb{P}$$
How many divisors does $n\alpha$ have? I did make some attempts but most of them were unsuccessful. For instance I considered $\frac {p^\alpha - 1}{p - 1}$ as a sum of geometric series but could not progress further.

Comment: ***p*** is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).